# Hot to call emacs within terminal.app from applescript when passing a file reference?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automation, emacs

I have been trying to make the below script work in mac Catalina with emacs installed via homebrew.

```
on open location this_URL
    set EC to "/usr/local/bin/emacsclient --no-wait "
    set filePath to quoted form of this_URL
    do shell script EC & filePath
    tell application "Emacs" to activate
end open location
```

when trying to save the script as application a pop-up asking `Choose Application` asks for `Where is Emacs?`  pops up . I tried to navigate to `/usr/local/bin` where my emacs are located but couldn't find the app . I clicked cancel and saved the app but whenever i try to access that app the very same popup is coming to view . What have i done wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: What Emacs distribution are you using?

Comment: @MarcWilson GNU Emacs 28.1 . Think the problem is calling the command line program like that , this is the first few lines of apple script i have written in my life .

Comment: I said what distribution of Emacs, not what version.

Comment: @MarcWilson Oh not sure , installed it with homebrew . How can i check the distribution ?

Comment: Cask or the other one?  homebrew cask for emacs is the emacsformacos.com distribution, which I use (the distribution, would never use homebrew).  That distribution of emacs expects to be in /Applications, no matter what symlinks homebrew might create.

Comment: which emacs gives /usr/local/bin/emacs and  which is symlinked to  ../Cellar/emacs/28.1/bin/emacs

Comment: Applescript is asking you to point out the actual application package it should activate.  It's not going to work with a naked emacs binary, if that's what homebrew has done.  It soulds like homebrew has created its standard maze of tiny symlinks for something completely straightforward.   Follow the synlinks to the actual .app package and that's what you point that dialog to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137632/discussion-between-anoop-d-and-marc-wilson).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort it out by editing the line

`tell application "Emacs" to activate`   to

`tell application "/usr/local/bin/emacs" to activate`

Thanks @MarkWilson for the time and help .